# How to make $arr2 from $arr1

Tags: php, arrays

It may be not difficult, but cost me half day, still unsolved.

Here are my code, `RESERVE_COUNT` is the number that duplicated.

$arr1 is here, $arr2 has no relationship with $arr1, just because I want $arr2, so I want to make $arr2 from existing $arr1. So $arr2 does not exist at first.

If not clear, I will explain better, just tell me.

```
//$arr1:
array(
    [0] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'A'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '09:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '10:00'
    )

    [1] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'B'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '13:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '14:00'
    ) 

    [2] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'A'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '09:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '10:00'
    ) 

    [3] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'A'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '10:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '11:00'
    ) 
)

//$arr2:
array(
    [0] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'A'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '09:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '10:00'
        ['RESERVE_COUNT'] => 2 //exactly same record appeared in $arr1 twice, so here is 2
    )

    [1] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'B'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '13:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '14:00'
        ['RESERVE_COUNT'] => 1
    ) 

    [3] =>
    array(

        ['CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL'] => 'A'
        ['STAFF_ID'] => 3010120001
        ['STAFF_START_TIME'] => '10:00'
        ['STAFF_END_TIME'] => '11:00'
        ['RESERVE_COUNT'] => 1
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Could you please express in words what the relation is between those two arrays? If you rely on us trying to spot the difference you may not get what you want.

Comment: You should really put some effort into explaining the manner you want them to be combined instead of relying on the effort of others. -1

Comment: Any one tell me can I just close the question, I don't want to be reduced reputation anymore. By the way, Thank you above two, I'm going to try solving this stuff myself try try.

Comment: @user1063434 - You can voluntarily delete the question, then go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and trigger a recalc to restore your rep. Some advice, if you rephrase the question and tell how $arr1 is related to $arr2, you can get some help.

Comment: I'm not able to find out which part of this question is not clear(also I see no reason here for downvotes). He want's to create a unique array $arr2 from $arr1 where 'RESERVE_COUNT' represents the occurence of duplicates in $arr1

Comment: @Dr.Molle - Thank you support! What you write is just what I meant. Now I cannot ask question anymore, because I meet "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more." . Who can tell me how to do and what to do to make me can ask question again using this account? Need I improve the quality of question? Need I do other else?

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing you can do is to request for removing the ban at  team@stackoverflow.com :( See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/stack-overflow-is-not-accepting-questions-from-my-account-anymore for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many ways.
for example:

```
$arr2=array();

foreach($arr1 as $value)//$arr1 is the given array
{
    //create a key for the new Array to make it unique
  $key=md5(serialize($value));
  $value['RESERVE_COUNT']=1;

    //if an entry already exist, add RESERVE_COUNT
  if(isset($arr2[$key]))$value['RESERVE_COUNT']+=$arr2[$key]['RESERVE_COUNT'];

  $arr2[$key]=$value;
}
print_r($arr2);
?>
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [450489089cc95e03d6c12dedb770a2a0] => Array
        (
            [CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL] => A
            [STAFF_ID] => 3010120001
            [STAFF_START_TIME] => 09:00
            [STAFF_END_TIME] => 10:00
            [RESERVE_COUNT] => 2
        )

    [8726c974e8d060b0dfdaab0aa29f5064] => Array
        (
            [CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL] => B
            [STAFF_ID] => 3010120001
            [STAFF_START_TIME] => 13:00
            [STAFF_END_TIME] => 14:00
            [RESERVE_COUNT] => 1
        )

    [003586db1308b821483d6bebc883a932] => Array
        (
            [CLASS_MENU_SYMBOL] => A
            [STAFF_ID] => 3010120001
            [STAFF_START_TIME] => 10:00
            [STAFF_END_TIME] => 11:00
            [RESERVE_COUNT] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I now study your code to try whether they work right now.

Comment: I tried, that's right. Thank you again.

Comment: Is this array coming from a DB? If yes there may be an easier way.

Comment: Yes, but not the raw data from db, the array has been processed to be $arr1, did you suggest using `count` and `group by`, anyway, I found your php way is really brilliant, I used it.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to build the array by SQL, it will be much faster, especialy when there are a lot of data.